# Azure service bus queue only receiving 450 messages at a time

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Does Azure have some kind of limitation in terms of batch items received? The following code is only retrieving 450 messages despite being asked for more:

```
QueueConnector.MyQueueClient.ReceiveBatch(1000, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
```

I've tried increased times, but it doesn't have any impact--450, every time. This appears to be the recommended way in the Azure SDK docs of batch receiving.

Note: there are tens of thousands of items in the queue.

Comment: Take a 2nd look at it. Are you sure you are accessing the right queue? Where are you dropping these messages?

Comment: 100% positive it's the right queue. I can watch the 450-at-a-time drop off on each request, despite `1000` being hard coded. My workaround for now is to continue receiving until the requested number is actually received.

Comment: What kind of application are you using to call this? Web Job? Worker Role? Web API?

Comment: I mean, maybe the application you are using is limited to X amount of connections or Y amount of data throughput?

Comment: Web API--no restrictions I'm aware of.

Comment: Did you ever find any reason why this is? We have the same problem, if we post 1000 messages, only some 50-70% of those appear when receiving, then after 1 min, the rest appears

Comment: I get exactly 256 messages every time. Very odd. I know my messages aren't 1k each.

Answer (score 1):

The count passed to the ReceiveBatch is an upper bound and that is also mentioned right in the docs, so this is expected behavior. Service Bus will release a batch based on message availability or batch size. Batches are capped at 256 kByte for send and receive. For SendBatch, that's also said in the docs.

Comment: I get exactly 256 messages every time. Very odd. I know my messages aren't 1k each.